# Perturbation theory, Feynman diagrams and Dyson equation for non-instantaneous two-particles interaction

Tags: condensed-matter, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory, second-quantization

In non-relativistic regime, the Coulomb interaction $W$ is instantaneous. In second quantization we can write it as (I am neglecting spin)

$$W=\sum_{r_1,r_2} W(r_1,r_2)\, \psi^{\dagger}(r_1)\psi^{\dagger}(r_2) \psi(r_2)\psi(r_1),$$

thus it is possible to use the standard perturbation theory through the interaction picture, and employ a diagrammatic analysis to evaluate the electron self-energy, as it is described for example in Gerald Mahan - "Many-particle physics" book, cap. 2 and cap. 3, for $T=0$ and $T\neq0$, respectively. In particular, when you write down the formulas describing the diagrams, you use the Heisenberg evolution of $W$, i.e. you have things like

$$W(t)=\sum_{r_1,r_2} W(r_1,r_2)\, \psi^{\dagger}(r_1,t)\psi^{\dagger}(r_2,t) \psi(r_2,t)\psi(r_1,t) .$$

Let us suppose we want to study the effect of a non-instantaneous interaction (like the phonon-mediated electron-electron effective interaction, but more in general). I have problems in putting down the problem in a clear and rigorous way. I have seen that we essentially have the same kind of diagrams, but now with the interaction written in this way:

$$W(t_1,t_2)=\sum_{r_\,r_2} W(r_1,t_1,r_2,t_2)\, \psi^{\dagger}(r_1,t_1)\psi^{\dagger}(r_2,t_2) \psi(r_2,t_2)\psi(r_1,t_1)$$

It is not clear to me:

1. What is the description of this interaction in the Schrodinger picture? Is it a time-dependent interaction $W(t_2-t_1)$?
2. How is the interaction picture defined? How do we obtain the perturbation expansion? Is the procedure similar to the one employed for the time-independent $W$?

I understand I am not very clear, that is because I am a bit confused. Maybe I will be able to refine the question after some feedback...